# setStatusBarOrientation not working

Tags: iphone, statusbar

I'm trying to fix the orientation of status bar to Portrait, but not succeeded. I have tried:

```
[application setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

and also `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is set to return `NO`.

Please help me out.

Comment: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` should return `YES` to the orientation that the viewController support, return `NO` for every orientation is not correct. If you support portrait orientation then return `YES` if the orientation is portrait.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the orientation when a particular view is showing, you should call [UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation:animated:] inside your [UIViewController viewWillAppear:] override method for each of the view controllers that force a particular orientation. That will cause a change when a view is being pushed onto the stack and when it's being popped off it. Make sure you call super in your override method.

Also change your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```