# Presented UIViewController refuses to rotate

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I'm using the DDMenuController in my app to have drawers like facebook app.

when navigation everything is perfect, using push method, the view rotate perfectly without doing anything;
but when I use [self present...] or [self.navigationcontroller present...] the view does note rotate, event worse the controllers shrinks and change positions.

the same view rotates fine if it is pushed. supportedInterfaceOrientation is made to support all but upside down should autorotate returns yes.

the sms part in Iphone is similar to what I want to do, a uinavigation bar in the top of a uitable, in the uinavigation bar there is a uitabbutton that presents a new uiviewController with a uinavigation bar and a uitextfield. The uinavigation button has a cancel uitabbutton and a save uitabbutton.

Thank you

Comment: I would use ECSlidingViewController personally

Comment: I already implemented DDMenuController and it's working great except for this. I can't go back now. but if this can't be solve I'll take sunday top recreate the app.
when I was looking for something to do the drawers I saw many examples but everyone is recommending DDMenuController because it is simpler.

Comment: It looks to me it is not simpler!

Comment: Well, I could take control of everything easily except for this one, if you can help me on this that would be great, if I couldn't get out I'll try an example with your suggestions to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting ECSlidingViewController, it did the job. although it is not simpler then DDmenu but I could manage, the things that bother now, are to add shadow to every uiviewController, add sliding button, clipping views, things that are automatically done by DDMenu. anyway better this than that. now if you want your comment to be as an accepted answer, please put it as answer. Thank you again so much

Answer (score 0):

I had problems rotating a view controller in one of my project, and I ended up implementing this solution, hope it will help you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);;


    switch (deviceOrientation) {
        case 1:
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            self.view.bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;
        case 2:
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown animated:NO];
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
            self.view.bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;
        case 3:
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
            //rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            self.view.bounds = rect;
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;
        case 4:
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
            //rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
            self.view.bounds = rect;
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I will use tomorrow and will reply you back, I'm at home and the mac is at the office, but before I have two questions :
you have disabled the autorotation, is that because you handle it manually in orientation changed?
I don't want to support the upside down so the code will still be fine if I omitted its case?
will this code work if I omitted this line :[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];??

Comment: yes I disabled the autorotation for this view because it was rotating with all the subviews, and some of them are not at 0,0 origin and this gives headache. You need the notification, otherwise orientationChanged will never be called. Only the viewcontroller where you add the code will be affected. And yes, you can omit case 2. Also you can change the animation duration to 0.3 if you want to make it look like the original autorotate.

Comment: It works like about 80%; the status bar is not rotating, so when it's in landscape, it becomes vertically in the left/right side and covering some of the view. I didn't skip anything yet.

Comment: setStatusBarOrientation should do the trick, for me works on IOS 5,6,7. Maybe you have set in a different manner your status bar.

Comment: normally should do, but it does not, I'm working for ios 6 only,

no I never touch it, this is the first time I do it with the code you gave me. do you have any suggetions how this happens

the weird thing is, when the view is pushed, every thing works fine When it is presented, I got the troubles

Comment: try the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034220/setstatusbarorientation-not-working. But firs, add the method 
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
} - see edited comment

Comment: No success at all, normally this should be automatic. status bar does not move unless you put shouldautorotate to yes, and that won't allow the code to work perfectly